# print form's output whitout realoding page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I wrote this form using html , PHP and javascript on my webpage. I want This form receives a number as input. and adds the desired number to 2 . And prints the output.

For example, I want if we put the number 5 at the input and press the submit button , the number 7 is printed on the output , **without reloading the page**.

But that doesn't happen. Because this command "document.getElementById("demo");" doesn't work properly.

What's wrong with me? **How can I create a form that receives input data And execute the desired commands on them and print the result in the output , *without reloading the page?***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'page-index112.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
            document.getElementById("demo");
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

<form name="form" action="" method="GET">
    <input type="number" name="sen" placeholder="سن">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="ثبت">
</form>

<?php 
    function zzz() {
        $sen1 = $_GET['sen'];
        if (empty($sen1)){ ?>
            <p id="demo"> <?php echo "ooopppss"; ?> </p>
        <?php }
        else {  ?>
            <p id="demo"> <?php echo $sen1 + 2; ?> </p> 
        <?php }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you doing this in WordPress?

Comment: @HowardE yes. in wordpress.

Comment: If you're using WordPress. What is this about? `url: 'page-index112.php',`  In WordPress, for ajax functions you should be using the admin-ajax.php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply wanted to solve the issue using plain JavaScript, that would be simple. That way, you wouldn't have to use PHP or AJAX for the calculation. Example also using JQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var sen = parseInt($('input[name="sen"]').val());
            $('#demo').html(sen + 2);
        });
    });
</script>



<form name="form" action="" method="GET">
<input type="number" name="sen" placeholder="سن">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="ثبت">
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Now, if you really want to use PHP for the calculations and you want to prevent loading a page, then you do have to use AJAX. But there are a few problems in your code. First of all, if you want to use JQuery, you will need to load it (for example by loading it from CDN)

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>`

The 'zzz' function is not required and doesn't do anything useful there. Since you're sending an AJAX request to page-index112.php, you just have to handle the data there.

So page-index112.php could simply contain something like this:

```
<?php
$sen = $_GET['sen'];
echo intval($sen) + 2;
```

and then your main script could work like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'page-index112.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    var demoElement = document.getElementById("demo");
                    demoElement.innerHTML = result;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="form" action="" method="GET">
<input type="number" name="sen" placeholder="سن">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="ثبت">
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

So that's basically the same result, but now you're using PHP to do the work on the back-end, but also without reloading the page.

I hope this explanation has helped you out!